# Doc is always null in the pullQueryBuilder

Tags: rxdb

I have set up graphql sync with a collection. The first sync runs fine, the data is populated, but after that I get an error like this:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): {"status":409,"name":"conflict","message":"Document update conflict"}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at zone-evergreen.js:705
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27148)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
```

I checked the network logs and it always queries documents with 0 `updatedAt` time. I have checked, and I always get `null` in the pullQueryBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the GraphQL sync is buggy with the indexeddb provider. I switched to the idb provider and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Hi Koppa. I am not aware of that problem, can you create an issue with a test case for that? Because we should fix that either on RxDB or PouchDB.